# Android - layout_weight - problem with size in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I need to create a layout that will have a certain aspect ratio and will be responsive.

The blocks are to be placed one above the other. I need to define the component in the following propositions:
Block 1: 10%
Block 2: 5%
Block 3: 60%
Block 4: 15%
Block 5: 10%

This is what my template looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/l0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to do this via layout_weight by determining:
Block 1: 1 or 10
Block 2: 0.5 or 5
Block 3: 6 or 60
Block 4: 1.5 or 15
Block 5: 1 or 10

But everything fell apart.

How it's working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add an image of paper sketch what you want to do

Comment: Ok, I know where I was doing wrong. I use parent layout orientation = vertical but children orientation = horizontal - then it doesn't work

After switching to vertical everywhere (parent + children), it works fine.

Comment: @mAsHER op question say you want to set the design vertically as given proportion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define `weightSum` to parent layout :

`android:weightSum` defines the maximum weight sum, and is calculated as the sum of the layout_weight of all the children if not specified explicitly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/l0"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @mAsHER works properly [img](https://prnt.sc/ui6xc1). Please check updated code

Answer (score 2):

You must set `android:layout_height="0dp"` to all children if the orientation of parent is vertical

Answer (score 1):

you have to add weightSum  to parent layout and change android:layout_weight="1" of the chiled as you want

is you put weightSum   = 10

and you want the Block 1: 10% make block 1 android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_height="0dp"

and you want the Block 2: 5% make block 2 android:layout_weight="0.5" and android:layout_height="0dp"

and you want the Block 3: 60% make block 3 android:layout_weight="6" and android:layout_height="0dp"

and so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to give "weight_sum="5"" to parent layout. And also need to change layout_width should be 0dp because it maintain the size of layout otherwise the layout will be expand according to data.
Example below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/l0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```